# Scandir variable not a string?

Tags: php, html

I have a piece of php code that lists directories and then creates div's with information regarding the directories inside of it. However when I do $newsPieces[i] it doesn't include the name of the folder in the string, why?

```
<?php
    $newsPieces = scandir("posts");
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($newsPieces) and $i < 10; $i++) {
        $titlefile = fopen($newsPieces[i] . "/title.txt", "r");
        $textfile = fopen($newsPieces[i] . "/text.txt", "r");
        $fullElement = "<div class='newsPiece'><div class='newsImageHolder'><img class='newsImage' src='" . $newsPieces[i] . "/image.jpg'></div><div class='newsContent'><h1 class='newsTitle'>" . fread($titlefile, filesize($newsPieces[i] . "/title.txt")) . "</h1><p class='newsText'>" . $piece[] = fread($textfile, filesize($newsPieces[i] . "/text.txt")) . "</p><a class='newsLink' href='post?post=" . urlencode($newsPieces[i]) . "'>Continue Reading</a></div></div>";
        echo $fullElement;
        fclose($titlefile);
        fclose($textfile);
    }
?>
```

Fixed Version:

```
<?php
    $newsPieces = scandir("posts");
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($newsPieces) and $i < 12; $i++) {
        $titlefile = fopen("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/title.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $textfile = fopen("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/text.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $fullElement = "<div class='newsPiece'><div class='newsImageHolder'><img class='newsImage' src='posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/image.jpg'></div><div class='newsContent'><h1 class='newsTitle'>" . fread($titlefile, filesize("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/title.txt")) . "</h1><p class='newsText'>" . fread($textfile, filesize("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/text.txt")) . "</p><a class='newsLink' href='post?post=" . urlencode($newsPieces[$i]) . "'>Continue Reading</a></div></div>";
        echo $fullElement;
        fclose($titlefile);
        fclose($textfile);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `i` should be `$i` -> `$newsPieces[$i]`. This was already brought up in a comment on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462680/error-in-php-code-that-gathers-information-about-blog-entries#comment50892169_31462806

Comment: Sadly that didn't work

Comment: what does `var_dump($newsPieces)` give you? is there a `$newsPieces[2]` through `$newsPieces[9]` value?

Comment: The length of the array is only 3 (and I skip the first two). Update: Chaning 'i' to '$i' did fix the problem however now I have the problem of the 'fread()' functions not working.

Comment: have you turn php error reporting on? are you getting an error message for `fread()`?

Comment: Fixed it, please see main post if you would like to know how